# What is the difference between nodejs packages workerpool & worker_threads?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Am new to JavaScript/NodeJs.
I tried to understand the difference between [child_process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html), [cluster](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) & [worker_threads](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html) and then confused after finding another module called [workerpool](https://www.npmjs.com/package/workerpool) so could you tell the difference between [worker_threads](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html) and [workerpool](https://www.npmjs.com/package/workerpool) in short, please?

Answer (score 1):

`workerpool` provides a **pool** of worker threads that it uses to run things: threads that can be reused, a new thread doesn't have to be created every time. As it says in the second sentence of the `npm` description, it implements the [worker pool pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool). `worker_threads` just provides a means of creating and using worker threads, it doesn't provide pooling. (Also, `workerpool` supports both Node.js and browsers, but `worker_threads` is of course Node.js specific.)